# BIOS will not allow changing to boot from new SSD

Tags: ssd, bios, boot

I have an [Intel DH67CL](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh67cl.html) motherboard, booting from a regular HDD. I then installed Windows on a new SSD after disconnecting my old drive.

When I went back to reconnect my old HDD, the BIOS boot menu will not let me select the new SSD as the preferred first boot option.

The BIOS settings only shows me the two hard drives, but I can't choose the new SSD as the BIOS prefers the old one.

How can I let the BIOS understands to load from SSD?

Comment: The BIOS doesn't move your OS to the new drive for you. Is that what you are asking about? Your question is not easy to understand. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Ensure that besides the "Boot Order", that there isn't also a separate entry for HDD order.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is due to Intel Fast Boot Technology. When booting speed is set to *fast*, the BIOS will try to boot from the drive attached to a specific port and ignore settings saying otherwise.

If that's the case, interchanging the two drives' SATA cables should suffice.